# display a image from the internet in gtk

Tags: c, gtk

I wanna display a image from the internet
how can I put it？

Comment: You'll have to be more specific if you want a good answer. What code do you already have, what library are you using to download the image, etc.

Comment: How about posting the code you have so far and tell us what part you're stuck on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show an image from URL using GTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089329/show-an-image-from-url-using-gtk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GTK+ doesn't read files from the Internet, you're going to have to do that part yourself.

Once you have the pixel data in memory in a known format (such as JPEG or PNG), call `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream()` (after setting up an in-memory stream) to load it.

Then hand that pixbuf to `gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf()`, add your GtkImage to a GtkWindow, call `gtk_widget_show_all()` on the window, and you should be done.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's an old post but I'll elaborate for anyone who stumbles upon this thread.

You'll want to use libsoup for this, it ties into the GLib main loop and can therefore work asynchronously.

https://libsoup.org/libsoup-2.4/libsoup-client-howto.html