# Show an image from URL using GTK[REPEAT]

Tags: c, linux, image, gtk, cairo

I have a problem with one thing. I searched about show an image from an url with cairo or gtk, but I didn't find anything.
If this is not possible, maybe I could decompose an image in a structure using other 
library, and then load it.

Any idea for do it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of an earlier question, also answered by our versatile friend @unwind ;-), but since the other question is terse at best, I'm voting to close that one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748538/display-a-image-from-the-internet-in-gtk

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962180/how-to-display-an-image-from-web

Answer (score 1):

GTK+ does not implement a HTTP protocol client, which would be needed in order to get the actual image bits from a URL.

You might want to look into using a dedicated library for that task, such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/).